# Get the path of a file dragged into a Windows Forms form

Tags: c#, winforms, file, drag-and-drop

I am developing an application which requires the user to drag a file from [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) into the application window ([Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form). Is there a way to read the file name, path and other properties of the file in C#?

Comment: There is a full example in *[Drag and Drop Text Files from Windows Explorer to your Windows Form Application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=192&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)*.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can catch the DragDrop event and get the files from there. Something like:

```
void Form_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

    //more processing
}
```

Comment: I'd also throw in a try/catch for InvalidCastException in case user tries dragging something else in!

Comment: I am not allowed to do a one character edit, so I am leaving this comment: FileList should be camel case: fileList

Comment: Holding File on the Form Doesn't allow me to Drop Files. Why? It Gives me The Not Allowed Sign..

Answer (score 5):

you Should Use Two Events
**1) DragDrop
2) DragEnter**

Also enable "AllowDrop" Property of Panel/form to **true**.

```
 private void form_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void form_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths= (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    }
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work, but this one does. Does anyone know why?