# C#: Drag & Drop File on .exe (icon) and get filepath

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I'm new to C# and I'm not getting around this trouble. Here is what I wanted to achieve.
Whenever I drag and drop a file on the .exe file (on the icon itself), the application should capture the filepath of dragged file.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try googling your problem? Any attempt to find a solution for yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the path of a file dragged into a Windows Forms form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364437/get-the-path-of-a-file-dragged-into-a-windows-forms-form)

Comment: What application you are developing..be more specific.

Comment: Yes Patrik. When I failed, that's when I signed up here to get an answer. Anyways, I'll try the link you've provided. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph. The focus is on getting the filepath of the file that dropped on exe icon. This filepath will be used later in the code to open that particular file. In short - Drag& drop file on this exe, file should open. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: This solved the similar issue for me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430941/drag-files-to-desktop-shortcut-not-opening-files-in-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to drop a file onto an icon of an exe, not an application itself. If that is so, it can be achieved easily using the parameters passed into the application. If you check your original boilerplate code when you make a console application it has the application entry point:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

If you drag drop a file onto the icon of the application, the args[0] will hold the name of the file being dropped. If the goal is to drop the file onto an EXE file, there are numerous tutorials on SO about that.

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I've just started to learn this technology. I missed such a silly one. By the way thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you make this following code, then when you drag your file onto the exe icon, the args[0] will hold the path of it as an argument:
 (I added the if statement that if you start the program without dragging anything
 it shouldn't crash)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add drag and drop onto an executable/shortcut created using Windows Forms by adding in the default `string[] args` to the `Main` function in `Program`.  And then, add the same parameter to `Form1`'s constructor function, and pass in the same `args` gathered from `Main`.

**Program.cs**

```cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    //add in the string[] args parameter
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //pass in the args to the form constructor
        Application.Run(new Form1(args));
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```cs
//add in the string[] args parameter to the form constructor
public Form1(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //if there was a file dropped..
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        var file = args[0];
        //do something with the file now...
    }
}
```